# Testing if an upload field will accept "click"

Tags: javascript, html

So, I would like to be able to have people click on a link, and the an input field with a file will open.  But I only want this to happen if the browser has support for it.  As pointed out [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133058/emulate-a-file-upload-click-in-jquery/4136396#4136396), chrome supports this.  Firefox 3.6 does not, but [Firefox 4 should](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications#Using_hidden_file_input_elements_using_the_click%28%29_method).

I know you can frequently test for support of features in javascript, but I'm unsure how to test for this feature.

If you'd like to see what I mean, the below code shows the feature when clicking on the link.  You can also [play with this on my page](http://cowsandmilk.net/test_click.html).

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Upload Field Click Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
             var clicker = document.getElementById('clicker');
             var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
             clicker.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                 uploader.click();
                 e.preventDefault();
             }, false);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="file" id="uploader">
        </form>
        <a href="#" id="clicker">Should click the uploader</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Things that do not work:

1. testing !uploader.click
2. seeing if uploader.click() throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to dynamically write the HTML into the document at the appropriate place

```
$("#mylinkID").after('<a href=" ">Whatever</a>');`
```

and the link would be added after the element that contained the ID "mylinkID". If no support for JS, the link doesn't get displayed.

Comment: I don't want to detect whether the browser has javascript.  I want to detect "Does the browser open the file upload dialog when I call the click function on a input[type="file"]?" and do it without sniffing the User-Agent

Comment: I'm guessing that the primary problem is the "addeventlistener" method which is not JQuery. I'm guessing that you would need a JQuery equivalent. See this thread at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398099/jquery-equivalent-of-javascripts-addeventlistener-method[/link] for details about this.